# Remove spaces in rows UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to do a UICollectionView with two columns. The first CollectionViewCell has a different size and I would like to remove the space with the next row. What I want:

[image: What I want]

What I get:

[image: What I get:]

Thanks!

EDIT: I have tried to use RFQuiltLayout, and still the same problem.
[image: Result with RFQuiltLayout]

The block default size:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
RFQuiltLayout* layout = (id)[self.collectionView collectionViewLayout];
layout.direction = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
layout.blockPixels = CGSizeMake(150, 220);
}
```

The first and all blocks size

```
- (CGSize) blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    return CGSizeMake(1, 0.5);
} else {
    return CGSizeMake(1, 1);
}

}
```

Comment: Did u figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [RFQuiltLayout](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rfquiltlayout) and [RAMCollectionViewFlemishBondLayout](https://github.com/TopicSo/RAMCollectionViewFlemishBondLayout)

[image]

Comment: @YagoGonzález: you can download the source code from provided link and run it!